# Applying RGBA Filter to SVG Image on Konva.js

Tags: konvajs, react-konva, konva

I've just replaced the .png file with my .svg file on this demo:
https://konvajs.org/docs/filters/RGBA.html
But filtering doesn't work, it says:
**konva.min.js.download:12 Konva error: Unable to apply filter. Failed to execute 'getImageData' on 'CanvasRenderingContext2D': The canvas has been tainted by cross-origin data.**

```
Konva.Image.fromURL('./graphic-01.svg', function (lion) {
    var stage = new Konva.Stage({
      container: 'container',
      width: window.innerWidth,
      height: window.innerHeight,
    });
```

Comment: You did not post enough code to confirm the issue, but it will be about a cross-origin issue.  Anything to do with image manipulation in browsers is by default very wary of allowing script from one website source to get images that have a source on another website url. Read up on cross-origin policy.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can CORS issue. It may not be possible to cache and filter images when HTML is opened as a local file from `file:` protocol.

For me information, please read [Tainted Canvas Docs](https://konvajs.org/docs/posts/Tainted_Canvas.html).

Comment: So I've changed the image url there with "https://paintbuilder-assets.s3.amazonaws.com/overlays/graphic-01.svg", and still same.
Seems like it happens only for svg

Comment: @RailsonSousa that images has no CORS headers. You need to configure AWS to allow CORS requests.